# Scroll bound hide header on scroll down and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple javascript problem that I can't seem to solve.

I want to make a header that hides on scroll down and shows on scroll up, but not with a simple trigger that goes from 0 to 100 on a threshold, but instead I want it to be bound to the scroll. Example: http://oma.eu/

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi and welcome, please read -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , then edit your question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with Headroom.js: https://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/

Comment: Thank you, although as with most examples out there it triggers and executes the entire animation at one threshold. What I'm looking for is to make the header act as if it has an absolute positioning, but follows the users scroll as if it was fixed. Just like (http://oma.eu/).

Comment: Ok if you want the `scrollspy`behavior the amazing `scrollmagic` can help you do that: http://scrollmagic.io/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in pure javascript without checking the **pageYOffset** of the **window**, there is a simple example on w3schools website, see the demo here:
[How To Hide Navbar on Scroll Down](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_hide_scroll)

**UPDATED:**

below is a demo of the updated fix *(using css transform translateY to set the position of the header)*:
[Demo solution](http://jsfiddle.net/moasmar/0ywn9fob/2/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px;margin-top:30px;">
  <p><b>This example demonstrates how to hide a navbar when the user starts to scroll the page.</b></p>
  <p>Scroll down this frame to see the effect!</p>
  <p>Scroll up to show the navbar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<script>
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.transform = "translate(0px, 0px)";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.transform = "translate(0px, -30px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, although as with most examples out there it triggers and executes the entire animation at one threshold. What I'm looking for is to make the header act as if it has an absolute positioning, but follows the users scroll as if it was fixed. Just like (http://oma.eu/).

Comment: I didn't get you, you mean parallax ? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Not parallax. Your first example is close. The one difference is that the header should not hide/show on a trigger. It should be bound to the scroll, so if I for instance scroll down 10px, the header follows those 10px via translateY or top. If you  try scrolling up and down on the OMA website and keep an eye on the header I think you will understand my crappy explanation.

Comment: ok so you need to use css translate and set it to desired position when scrolling down, and reset it to 0 when scrolling up (use same example provided and add the css)
here is a jsfiddle from above example:
http://jsfiddle.net/moasmar/0ywn9fob/2/
I updated the answer.